# Bullet Physics, Collision between btBvhTriangleMeshShape and btStaticPlaneShape wont work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, bullet, bulletphysics

First some facts:
I try to realise Collision Detection with Bullet in C++ using Visual Studio 2012.
 So far i have a Sphere:

```
    btCollisionShape* fallShape = new btSphereShape(100); 
    btDefaultMotionState* fallMotionState =
            new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1),btVector3(0,500,0)));
    btScalar mass = 1000;
    btVector3 fallInertia(0,0,0);
    fallShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass,fallInertia);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass,fallMotionState,fallShape,fallInertia);
    btRigidBody* fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
    physicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
```

and my level, realised as btBvhTriangleMeshShape:

```
    triangles.addTriangle(btVector3 (0, 0, 0),btVector3 (0, 0, 0),btVector3 (0, 0, 0));

btCollisionShape* levelShape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(&triangles, true, true);
    btDefaultMotionState* levelMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1),btVector3(0,0,0)));
  btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo
      levelRigidBodyCI(0,levelMotionState,levelShape,btVector3(0,0,0));
   btRigidBody* levelRigidBody = new btRigidBody(levelRigidBodyCI);
    physicsWorld->addRigidBody(levelRigidBody);
```

I know that in triangles is only one triangle but they collide.

My Problem is now, that when they collide, my program shuts down with no specific error, simply a unhandle exception window from visual studio.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
triangles.addTriangle(btVector3 (0, 0, 0),btVector3 (0, 0, 0),btVector3 (0, 0, 0));
```

You are giving all coordinates the zero value, so the triangle is not correct and maybe that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, here below is a short working example in C++ of a flat `btBvhTriangleMeshShape`, inspired by the question above. Mass is `0.0f` as the mesh is obviously a static object.

```
btVector3 vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, vertex4;
btTriangleMesh* triangleMeshTerrain = new btTriangleMesh();

for (int i = -250; i < 250; i = i + 10) {
    for (int j = -250; j < 250; j = j + 10) {

        vertex1 = btVector3(i, 0.0f, j);
        vertex2 = btVector3(i + 10.0f, 0.0f, j);
        vertex3 = btVector3(i + 10.0f, 0.0f, j + 10.0f);
        vertex4 = btVector3(i, 0.0f, j + 10.0f);

        triangleMeshTerrain->addTriangle(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3);
        triangleMeshTerrain->addTriangle(vertex1, vertex3, vertex4);
    }
}

btCollisionShape* collisionShapeTerrain = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(triangleMeshTerrain, true);

btDefaultMotionState* motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, -15, 0)));

btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rigidBodyConstructionInfo(0.0f, motionState, collisionShapeTerrain, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
btRigidBody* rigidBodyTerrain = new btRigidBody(rigidBodyConstructionInfo);
rigidBodyTerrain->setFriction(btScalar(0.9));

m_dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(rigidBodyTerrain);
```